# Where should the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' terms be placed?

Tags: php, wordpress

As a relative newbie to php coding, I am currently relying on YouTube tutorials, to help me with creating a WordPress theme from scratch.

I have got to the point whereby I would like to use php to insert a Blog post beneath a page's content.  Following the YouTube tutorial, I have created the following code:

```
<?php       
    $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1&category_name=news');

        if ( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
            while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); 
    ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content/content',get_post_format()); 
        ?>

    <?php 
            endwhile;
        endif;                  
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Is the above code correct?  I am not 100% as my logical mindset is telling me that the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' statements should be placed between:

```
        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post();
    ?>
```

It would be greatly helpful, if anyone is able to clarify this matter.

Many thanks.

Craig

Comment: Hi Craig, the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' statements are perfectly fine where they are. Whereabouts in the second code block is your logical mindset telling you to put them? Maybe I can help clarify if I know how you think it 'should' look.

Comment: Hi @Ben Plummer, Thanks for responding.  I was thinking that given the 'if' and 'while' statements are in between the first <?php ?> tag, then so should the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' statements.  More precisely, be placed after:  'while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>' but before the closing '?>'  I hope I have explained this correctly :-)

Comment: No worries. See my answer below that hopefully clarifies things for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP there is no rule or practice of having to have the end of statements e.g. 'endwhile;', 'endif;' etc within the same set of PHP tags.

If you only have PHP inside the relevant statements (if, while etc), it is likely that all of it could be placed in one set of PHP tags, rather than for instance the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' statements being in a separate set. In this case, your code does not contain HTML or any markup explicitly so it could also be written all in one set of PHP tags like so:

```
<?php       
    $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1&category_name=news');

    if ( $lastBlog->have_posts() ) {
        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ) {

            $lastBlog->the_post(); 

            // Added 'echo' to output the content
            echo get_template_part('content/content',get_post_format()); 

        } // End of 'while' statement
    } // End of 'if' statement

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Although the current state of your code could be written like that, it is perfectly fine the way it is and the current structure that you have allows you to add HTML explicitly if you need to e.g.:

```
<?php       
    $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1&category_name=news');

    if ( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); 
?>

<?php get_template_part('content/content',get_post_format()); ?>

<p>HTML EXAMPLE - THIS WOULD APPEAR FOR EACH POST IN THE WHILE LOOP</p>

<?php 
        endwhile;
    endif;                  
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This example above is just a demonstration of having HTML explicitly amongst the different sets of PHP code blocks in your code. I'm aware that the 'get_template_part' call in your code is actually responsible for the HTML output.

All in all, your code and statements are fine the way they are. If you did move the 'endwhile;' and 'endif;' statements to where your logical mindset told you, this would mean that the 'get_template_part' call would be outside of the 'if' and 'while' statement. Whilst this may not change the way your page works currently (as you are only outputting one post), if you decided that you want more posts outputted there the code would not work as the 'get_template_part' method would only get called once (and not for each post) due to it being outside the 'while' loop. Leave your code structured the way it is and it should work for outputting one post or many if you ever changed the WP_Query.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer Ben.  Much appreciated.  Still lots of learning to do on my behalf but your reply has certainly helped to provide further clarity on how statements work. :-)

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! Good luck with the learning :)